# OnChange and AutoComplete both not working withHtml.TextBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying with MVC and Jquery.
I have defined a textbox like this `<td>@Html.TextBox("SearchParam")</td>`
and my script as below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#SearchParam').change(function () {
            var source = $.ajax({
                url: "/Search/SearchText",
                type: "post",
                async: false,
                data: { searchText: $('#SearchParam').val() },
                //success: function (result) {
                //    alert("Data");
                //}
            });

            $('#SearchParam').autocomplete({
                dataType: "json",
                source: source
            });
        });


    });
    //function onSearchParamChange(){
    //    var source = $.ajax({
    //        url: "/Search/SearchText",
    //        type: "post",
    //        async: false,
    //        data: { searchText: $('#SearchParam').val() },
    //        //success: function (result) {
    //        //    alert("Data");
    //        //}
    //    });

    //    $('#SearchParam').autocomplete({
    //        dataType: "json",
    //        source: source
    //    });
    //};

    $("#submitButton").click(function () {
       // var data = new FormData($("#searchFrm")[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Search/Search",
            type: "post",
            data: $("#searchFrm").serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                $("#partialBody").html(result);
            }
        });
    }); </script>
```

You can notice that I tried with onSearchParamChange() function also by defining the textbox as below:

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchParam", null,new { @onchange = "onSearchParamChange();" })
```

but the following problems remain same:
1. The TextBox Change event is not fired when the text gets changed, rather it is firing while the text box lost focus or blur..
2. Even when it loose focus the data is returned correctly, but autocomplete does not work..
I am using MVC 3 with jquery ui 1.8.20 and testing in Chrome..
Pls help..

Answer (score 1):

I see three issues:

1. Your autocomplete isn't set up until the `change` event fires, instead it should be initialized once when the page loads.
2. You aren't defining your remote datasource properly. Re-read [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), and see the ["multiple, remote" example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote) for an idea of how to pass a function to the source property.
3. *"The TextBox Change event is not fired when the text gets changed, rather it is firing while the text box lost focus or blur"* - This is working as designed. Implementing this yourself, you would want to use the `keyup` event. But the autocomplete plugin will handle that for you.

Answer (score 1):

when you create element `@Html.TextBox("SearchParam")` you just defined the elements name, so you will have something like `<input name="SearchParam" type="text" />`

you can try this `@Html.TextBox("SearchParam", null,new { id="SearchParam" })`

you should use `onkeypress` event

```
    $('[name=SearchParam]').keypress(function (e) {
        var source = $.ajax({
            url: "/Search/SearchText",
            type: "post",
            async: false,
            data: { searchText: $('[name=SearchParam]').val() },
            //success: function (result) {
            //    alert("Data");
            //}
        });

        $('[name=SearchParam]').autocomplete({
            dataType: "json",
            source: source
        });
    });
```